# Ruby interpolation in javascript not working in 1 of 2 instances

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, erb

I am trying to interpolate some ruby code within a  tag at the bottom of my html.erb file. For some reason, the first example (ending in company_email), works just like a charm while the second, for some unknown reason, returns the string {@custom_landing_page_company.name}. Can anyone explain why the same method of interpolation works in one case and not the other? Thank you.

```
$.validator.addMethod("biogenEmail", function(value, element) {
  return value.indexOf("#{@custom_landing_page_company.company_email}") !== -1;
 }, "Please enter a valid #{@custom_landing_page_company.name} email address");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll work anyway:

```
$.validator.addMethod("biogenEmail", function(value, element) {
  return value.indexOf("<%= @custom_landing_page_company.company_email %>") !== -1;
}, "Please enter a valid <%= @custom_landing_page_company.name %> email address");
```

I've used `<%= %>` instead of `#{}`.

I'm not sure why the second one doesn't work, but I've found that using `<%= %>` in erb always works.

Comment: Yup. Works. Thought I had already tried that out. Now I feel dumb.